# Why does the delta-V for LEO-KSC to LEO-Equatorial orbit seem unusually high?

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science

After reading [Q36179](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/would-a-rocket-burn-more-fuel-to-get-from-earths-surface-to-leo-or-to-get-from) and [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth.E2.80.93Moon_space.E2.80.94high_thrust) on the Wikipedia page for Delta-V budget (also linked from Q36179), I'm curious:

Why does going from a [KSC](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/home/)-launched [LEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) to an orbit like one launched from the equator seem to require so much $\mathrm{\Delta V}$?  $\mathrm{4.24~\frac{km}{s}}$ is almost half of what's required just to get to LEO to begin with, and that's factoring in a prograde launch!

Isn't this just a change in [orbital inclination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination)?  KSC is "only" [28.57](https://www.google.com/search?q=lat%20and%20lon%20of%20kennedy%20space%20center)$^{\circ}$ N. latitude.

Related question:  Is there a general formula for determining $\mathrm{\Delta V}$ given the initial and final (or change of) inclination? My intuition says that some [trig](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trigonometry.html) functions would be involved.

Comment: I can tell you from playing KSP that plane changes are very expensive. You have to cancel a lot of vertical velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't this just a change in orbital inclination?

"Just" is one of the most dangerous words in science and engineering.

Plane changes are very expensive in terms of delta V costs. Changing orbital inclination is a plane change. The cost to make an inclination change from a circular orbit to another circular orbit, with no change in orbital altitude, is $\Delta v = 2v\sin(\Delta i / 2)\ $.

For example, the delta V needed to change from a geosynchronous orbit with an inclination of 28 degrees to a geostationary orbit is 1.4 km/s. The delta V cost to successively go from a low Earth orbit inclined at 28 degrees to a geostationary orbit inclined at 28 degrees and then to a geosynchronous orbit is 5.3 km/s.

That three burn sequence (one in LEO to transfer to geosynchronous altitude, a second at geosynchronous altitude to circularize the orbit, and a third at the node to transfer to geostationary) is not how it's done. Delta V costs are nonlinear, thanks to the nonlinear way in which gravitation works. The result is a savings of about one km/s compared to that three burn sequence, but it's still more expensive than launching from the equator.

Regarding the wikipedia page on delta V budget, you have to take that page with a **huge** grain of salt.

Comment: Should I assume that the word "only" (in the next sentence) is equally dangerous?  Note that I did put [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) around it. ;-)

Comment: Also, my original question assumed a change in orbital inclination but remaining a low-Earth orbit.  Does an orbital plane change remaining at **LEO** require a transfer to geosynchronous orbit and back?