# Saturn V specific impulse issue in velocity modelling with Tsiolkovsky's equation against actual values?

Tags: velocity, rocket-science

I've been trying to model the Saturn V's velocity using Tsiolkovsky's ideal rocket equation, and in the process, I think I may have made a mistake with regards to the specific impulse?

**I've come up with the following equation**, taking the change in gravity into account:
$$ \Delta v(t) = I_\mathrm{sp} g_0 \left(\frac{R_\oplus}{a(t)+R_\oplus}\right)^2 \ln\left(\frac{m_0}{m_0-c(t)}\right). $$
$a(t) = 0.0033 t^2 - 0.1462 t + 1.9487$ is the altitude function derived from actual values, with a very small error range, and $c(t) = 12579.9 t$ is the fuel consumption of the rocket per second. Also I have
\begin{align}
\Delta v & && \text{change in velocity} \\
t & && \text{time elapsed} \\
I_\mathrm{sp} & = 263\ \mathrm{s} && \text{specific impulse time} \\
g_0 & = 9.81\ \mathrm{m/s^2} && \text{acceleration of gravity on Earth} \\
R_\oplus & = 6371\ \mathrm{km} && \text{radius of Earth} \\
m_0 & = 2{,}800{,}000\ \mathrm{kg} && \text{gross mass of Saturn V rocket.}
\end{align}

**And this a plot of the model** I created versus the actual values plotted against time:

[image: velocity versus time]

The percentage error here between the two sets of values vary from ~80% to ~14%, and the graph shape is vastly different.

I'd like to ask if there is a change in specific impulse? Or have I done anything else wrong in modelling the equation above?

Also, I apologize if I've made a stupid mistake, I'm a HS student doing some fun research, quite new to this!

Comment: Note that this site uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for rendering LaTeX equations. I don't have time at the moment to edit your post but you can have a look at the MathJax site or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) or click "edit" on any of the questions with equations on this site to get an idea how it works.

Comment: Yes, specific impulse changes during ascent due to reduction of pressure on the outside.

Comment: At any time there is guaranteed to be at least one grad student around who is looking for ways to avoid research. Karan K: if you aren't familiar with Latex, it's a great thing to learn. You can click edit on this question now to see how I formatted things - and at least 95% of what I did is "proper" and not a hack :)

Comment: What about drag??

Comment: Thank you for the links, @MichaelBrown! :) Will definitely read up!

Comment: Ooh, thank you @DeerHunter! :) Would the equation shown here for Isp http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/difference-between-deltav-and-specific-impulse be the way to go for expressing a change in Isp? Also I've decided not to consider drag initially, though I will once I figure out the change in Isp. Thank you, once again! :)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, @ChrisWhite! That's incredible. :) If I had enough rep to upvote you, I would! Haha. Thank you, once again! I'll definitely check out LaTex. :)